# Can I sync multiple live radio streams with video?

Tags: html5-video, audio-streaming

Is it possible to sync multiple live radio streams to a pre-recorded video simultaneously and vary the volume at defined time-indexes throughout? Ultimately for an embedded video player.

If so, what tools/programming languages would be best suited for doing this?

I've looked at `Gstreamer`, `WebChimera` and `ffmpeg` but am unsure which route to go down.

Comment: What do you mean by sync?  If the audio is separate from the video, synchronization is almost impossible in any case.  If you just want to play them at the same time and control the volume with video time (that is, the audio can be at any point, but faded in an out) that's different.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with [WebChimera](http://www.webchimera.org/), as it is open source and extremely flexible.

- The best possible implementation of this is in QML by modifying the .qml files from [WebChimera Player](https://github.com/jaruba/WebChimeraPlayer) directly with any text editor.
- The second best implementation of this is in JavaScript with the [Player JS API](http://wiki.webchimera.org/Player_JavaScript_API).

**The difference between these two methods would firstly be resource consumption.**

The second method that would use only JavaScript would require adding one `<object>` tag for the video, and one more for each audio file you need to play. So for every media source you add to the page, you will need to call a new instance of the plugin.

While the first method made only in QML (mostly knowing JavaScript would be needed here too, as that handles the logic part behind QML), would load all your media sources in one plugin instance, with multiple `VlcVideoSurface` components that each has it's own [Plugin QML API](https://github.com/RSATom/WebChimera/wiki/QML-API).

The biggest problem I can foresee for what you want to do is the buffering state, as all media sources need to be paused as soon as one video/audio starts buffering. Synchronizing them by time should not be to difficult though.

[WebChimera Wiki](http://wiki.webchimera.org/WebChimera_Wiki) is a great place to start, it has lots of demos and examples. And at [WebChimera Questions](http://ask.webchimera.org/) we've helped developers modify WebChimera Player to suit even the craziest of needs. :)